# What is a more efficient way to log an output file in a database

Tags: sql, asp.net, xml

I have a bunch of unit tests I run daily, that create huge log files. Currently I store these in XML format in a database, then my dashboard website parses through the XML and generates an ASP.NET page based on the files.

The problem im getting now is for the longer test the ASP page is actually timing out as the log files are so long.

So would it be better to store the log as a text file in the database then just stick it all in a div?

Im not really sure where to go from here, its worked fine in the past but these tests are a lot longer and generate a huge number of "lines" in the log file. Maybe my XML parser isnt as quick as it could be.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated